# С какой буквы писать слово "земля" – с прописной или строчной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

*Гости съехались со всех уголков Земли.*

Comment: У шара нет "уголков", поэтому земля в этом старом фразеологизме плоская, а буква - как у классиков.

Comment: А как у классиков?

Comment: С маленькой (Вновь я посетил тот уголок земли...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересная дискуссия "На Земле или на земле" есть на сайте [**"Большой вопрос.ru"**](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1152662-na-zemle-ili-na-zemle-bolshuju-ili-malenkuju-bukvu-pisat.html):

Все зависит от того, в каком смысле мы будем употреблять это слово.
Если слово используется как название небесного тела или планеты, то "Земля" является в этих случаях именем собственным и всегда пишется с большой буквы.
Если слово "земля" используется в качестве места жительства людей, верхнего слоя земной коры, суши, сельскохозяйственных владений, почвы или грунта, то первая буква этого слова строчная.
Заглавная буква может использоваться при необходимости подчеркнуть *значимость* нашего слова — как авторский вариант.

Значение слова **"Земля"** [**по Ефремовой**](http://tolkslovar.ru/z5647.html):
1. Одна из девяти — третья от Солнца — больших планет Солнечной системы.
2. Третья от Солнца планета Солнечной системы как место жизни и деятельности человека.

У Пушкина:
*...Вновь я посетил

Тот **уголок земли**, где я провёл

Изгнанником два года незаметных.*

У Гончарова:
*Где мы? В какой благословенный **уголок земли** перенёс нас сон Обломова? Что за чудный край!*

Для вашего предложения я вижу три возможности.

1. [Юбилей любимого преподавателя.] Гости съехались со всех уголков земли.
2. Два варианта:
   [Международный кинофестиваль.] Гости съехались со всех уголков земли.
   [Симпозиум вулканологов планеты.] Гости съехались со всех уголков Земли.
3. [Космический контакт.] Гости съехались со всех уголков Земли.

Comment: У журналистов можно встретить и "уголки [круглой] планеты", но что-то в этой перефразировке есть от "порывшейся собаки" :) .

Comment: @Alex_ander У слова *уголок' много смыслов помимо  геометрического угла. Уголком называют отдельный участок чего-л., часть какой-л. территории, местности и т.п. Тихий, укромный у. (уединённое место). Облюбовал себе для отдыха чудесный у. в Карелии. Живописный у. Крыма (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: Как правило, это упрощения от "уголок земли" (в "землемерном" смысле).

Answer (score 4):

Я бы написал со строчной. Не на Марсе же они собрались. См. для сравнения, как пишет известный лингвист Владимир Плунгян в книге "Почему языки такие разные":

> Конечно, и люди в разных частях земли не похожи друг на друга, они отличаются ростом, цветом глаз, волос или кожи, наконец, обычаями.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, написание этого слова с прописной буквы уместно только в контексте космоса.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно с прописной, потому что имеется в виду планета Земля, где *Земля* — имя собственное.